# internal DNS setup at our different offices but i was contemplating if it makes sense to use a Azure private DNS server

Tags: azure, azure-dns, azure-private-dns

we have some internal DNS setup at our different offices but i was contemplating if it makes sense to use a Azure private DNS server.In confusion whether its a sensible thing to do or it is not a best practice yet.Is this feature generally available or it is still in preview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. The steps are:

- Create an Azure private DNS Zone
- Connect the private DNS Zone to an Azure Virtual Network
- Connect the Azure Virtual Network to your on prem network

For details see:

https://edi.wang/post/2019/8/9/create-a-private-dns-server-without-vm-on-microsoft-azure

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/connect-an-on-premises-network-to-a-microsoft-azure-virtual-network?view=o365-worldwide